# Остановка setInterval JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
var but1 = document.getElementById('but1');

function start(){
var id = setInterval(func,time)
....
}
```

Как записать выражение, если была нажата кнопка but1 в HTML, то остановить setInterval(func,time)?
без Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id;
function start(){
  id = setInterval(func,time);
  ....
}
but1.addEventListener('click', () => clearInterval(id));
```